# Interpreting literal HTML tags from text file

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, dom

I am using Flask with Jinja2 templating to build a static webpage. I am sourcing page texts from .txt files. What I want to do is to pass literal HTML tags from the .txt file and have it interpreted in the DOM. Currently, the text it represented literally, and if I look at the page source, the tags are interpreted in escape characters.

**Text**

```
The map uses the <a href="google.com">Google</a> API.
```

**HTML**

```
<p>{{ text }}</p>  <!-- text above goes here -->
```

The anchor tag is not represented as an HTML tag, but rather like this:

```
&lt;a href=&#34;google.com&#34;&gt;google&lt;/a&gt;
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#autoescape-overrides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This arises because Flask will automatically escape any HTML tags contained in your template variables, to avoid common security concerns.

See the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#controlling-autoescaping) for how to disable this - one simple way is to replace `{{ text}}` with `{{ text|safe}}`.

But note that you must not do this if the `text` variable can come from an "unsafe" source, such as an untrusted user.